# Difference between " | " or " & " for calculations and inside IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

**I'm trying using `|` inside a IF (or SWITCH) statement to compare if a variable is equal to a number or another.**
But I found (described as an example in code below) that using `|` operator to two numbers that I wanna compare is the same result as I put an `||` for two comparisons. But if I declare another variable that ORs these two numbers using `|`, the if statement won't execute:

(This is "almost" the full code)

```cpp
using namespace std;
short n1 = 5, n2 = 3, n3, nResult;
n3 = 3; // used for two comparisons
nResult = n1 | n2; // used for the second comparison (IF statement)
    
bitset<16> n1_b(n1), n2_b(n2), n3_b(n3), nr_b(nResult); // I used bitset to check their binary value
    
if (n3 == nResult) 
    cout << "nResult YES";
else if (n3 == n1 | n2) 
    cout << "n1 | n2 YES";
    
/* cout << endl << n1_b << endl << n2_b << endl << n3_b << endl << endl << nr_b; */
```

The output is always `n1 | n2 YES`.
Why using `m3 == n1 | n2` inside IF statement gave the same result as using `n3 == n1 || n3 == n2`, and why if I ORed before will not execute?

Comment: The single pipe is the bitwise OR. which means 6 | 3 = 7.

Comment: Don't forget [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) which means `x == y | z` evaluates as `(x == y) | z`.

Comment: Really you should try looking up what `|` and `&` really do. At the moment you seem to be making stuff up and then being surprised when it's not correct. `|` and `&` are *bitwise* operators, not logical operators.

Comment: `5 | 3` does not  mean "the value `5` or the value `3`" it means `7`.

Comment: That's my problem about the question. I should delete the SWITCH case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in this if statement

```
else if (n3 == n1 | n2)
```

is equivalent to

```
else if ( ( n3 == n1 ) | n2)
```

The subexpression `n3 == n1`  ( `3 == 5` ) yields boolean value `false` that used in expressions is implicitly converted to `0`.

So

```
0 | n2
```

gives non-zero value equal to `n2`.

Thus the result of the expression is boolean `true`..

As for this if statement

```
if (n3 == nResult)
```

then `nResult` calculated like `nResult = n1 | n2;` is equal to `7` that is not equal to `n3`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if a number is "one of a set of possible answers" then there's a few approaches.

For example, given `n` and a set like `3, 5, 9` you can use `if`:

```
if (n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 9) {
  // Matches
}
```

You can use `switch`:

```
switch (n) {
  case 3:
  case 5:
  case 9:
    // Matches
    break;
}
```

You can use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> matches = { 3, 5, 9 };

if (std::find(matches.begin(), matches.end(), n) != matches.end()) {
  // Matches
}
```

You can use a `std::set`:

```
std::set<int> matches = { 3, 5, 9 };

if (matches.find(n) != matches.end()) {
  // Matches
}
```

You can use a bitmap index:

```
std::bitset<10> matches = "0001010001";

if (matches[n]) {
  // Matches
}
```

What you can't do is use the `|` operator to just smash numbers together.